# Business Objects 4.1 - RESTFul Scheduling Webi doc with prompts (XML avoid DPID and ID)

Tags: xml, restful-url, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I'm trying Business Objects 4.1 RESTful API to schedule Webi Report with prompts (parameters) using an XML payload.

If I schedule (call `POST ../<REPORTID>/schedules/`) a doc. without specify the **dpId** property and the *`<id>`* tag into *`<parameters>`* tag group (view following example),I get and error.

Example (working payload):

```
...
<parameter optional="false" type="prompt" dpId="DP0">
  <id>0</id>
    <technicalName>Enter values for City:</technicalName> 
     <values> 
     <value>Austin</value>
    </values> 
   </parameter>
</parameters>
```

Using Java SDK in BI3.x for schedule Prompt class, I was able to identify a prompt using only its name (avoiding the id and dpId data). I would avoid using this additional information. Is it possibile?

Assuming that's not possible, and so it's necessary look for them by callin `GET` `../<REPORTID>/parameters`, my question is **when DPID and ID will change?**

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use the *prompt name* with the REST API. But, you can obtain the identifier of the prompt by requesting the parameter list and looking for your prompt name.
See calls:

- `[GET] <url>/documents/<documentId>/parameters` (available since 4.0 SP5)
- `[GET]/documents/{documentId}/dataproviders/{dataproviderId}/parameters`  (available since 4.1 SP3)

About the lifecycle of identifiers:

- `DPID` will not change if you don't remove it or apply a changesource on your document/dataprovider
- `ID` may be updated if you edit your query